# how can I convert an object of type Any to a specific class type?

Tags: json, kotlin, serialization

I am using Kotlin and I have a service that is getting an object of type Any (this cannot be changed)

The problem with Any is that is an object of 20+ fields and I just need one of them to use it as a filter... therefore I cannot do a simple cast.

So, my object is like: (when I print it)

```
{messageId=123, userId=32323, address=Some city, phone=111605,type=TYPE1.....
```

I want to convert it using Kotlinx or Jackson but I cannot convert it first to the expected String format, doing a `parseFromString(myObject)` will result in an exception as well of a wrong Json format.

I want to convert it to a class like this

```
@Serializable
private data class UserType(val type: String)
```

type is the only field I care about.

My convertion is via kotlinx

```
val format = Json { ignoreUnknownKeys = true }
format.decodeFromString<UserType>(myObject)
```

I even tried this to see if I can make it in the proper Json format

```
format.encodeToString(original)
```

Any idea what I could do here that would be a lightweight solution?

This is my `Any` type https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-any/

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your problem. Do you mean `Any` as Kotlin's [Any](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-any/) or do you have a class named `Any`? Why do you have an object with some fields and you can't easily access one of them?

Comment: I meant Kotlin's Any. The object has another function, unfortunately, now before send it to that function I need to filter it and for that I need to access to that field

Comment: Ok, so what do you mean that you can't do a cast? The property that you are interested in has to be a part of some interface/class and you should be able to cast to it.

Comment: They are part of a class/interface that is not defined by me, and I would like to avoid casting the whole object by defining a class with all the parameters I'm receiving given would not be adequate for the system

Comment: Sorry, I'm really confused :-) `Any` can't really have any properties. Your object isn't really `Any`, it is `SomeThirdPartyClass` and you just see it as `Any`. You need to identify what is its true type and cast to this type. Even if you would define your own class with the same properties, you wouldn't be able to cast to it, because casting does not work this way.

Comment: Start by calling `::class` on this object and print the result to see what this object really is. Or better, use a debugger for this purpose. Maybe it is just a `Map<String, Any>`?

Comment: Actually, it really looks like a `Map<String, Any>`. If this is the case try: `(myObject as Map<String, Any>)["type"]`. Then you need to cast the result to whatever this `TYPE1` thing is. Also, you would need to make sure (documentation of this API?) that this `Any` is always a map, because it may depend on some condition.

Comment: @broot thanks! thats actually the way has to be done!